# OpenLDAP BDB log file maintenance and auto removal

Tags: ldap, openldap, berkeley-db

I have a question about the log files OpenLDAP/BDB creates in the data directory. These files have the form `log.XXXXXXXXXX` (X is a digit) and each has the same size (which is configurable in DB_CONFIG).

I read a lot about checkpointing and log file maintenance in the OpenLDAP and BDB documentatioon. It seems to be normal that these files grow very fast and need maintenance. Normally you should backup them regularly and delete them afterwards. But how to handle this during a long running data migration?

In my case running a test migration for 375 accounts which triggers 3 write requests per account to the LDAP server produces 6 log files with 5 MB each. The problem ist there are more than 37000 accounts on the live system that need to be migrated and the creation of several gigabytes of log files is not accepted.

Because of that I tried to configure auto removal of the log files but the suggested solution is not working for me. After reading through the documentation, my conclusion was that I have to enable checkpoints via slapd.conf and set the `DB_LOG_AUTOREMOVE` flag in the `DB_CONFIG` file like this:

My settings in slapd.conf:

```
checkpoint 128 15
```

My settings in DB_CONFIG:

```
set_flags DB_LOG_AUTOREMOVE
set_lg_regionmax 262144
set_lg_bsize 2097152
```

But the log files are still there - even if I decrease the checkpoint settings to `checkpoint 1 1`. If I run `slapd_db_archive -d` in the data directory all of these files but the very last get removed.

Does anyone have an idea how the get the auto removal working? I am close to giving up and add a cron job to run `slapd_db_archive -d` during the migration. But I am not sure if this may cause problems.

We are using OpenLDAP 2.3.43 with the BDB Backend (HDB to be precise) on centos.

Comment: If you're using HDB why are you asking about BDB options?

Comment: @EJP because it is more or less the same (configuration-wise): http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/backends.html

Answer (score 0):

In BDB (dunno HDB), DB_LOG_AUTOREMOVE removes log.* files that do not reference records currently in the database. This is not the same as removing all log files.

Comment: I add this comment, to make the question Up because the problem is still here.
Is it normal that `db_archive -d` remove the logs (all but the last refernced by database)?

But DB_LOG_AUTOREMOVE does nothing.